# How to run lisp scripts by passing arguments from Java

Tags: java, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to run lisp scripts by passing arguments from Java.

For eg: 
In the below script, the value of x should be passed from Java code.

```
(defun double (x) (* x 2))
```

Could you please give some examples?

Comment: Honestly, I'd suggest just learning Clojure. A lisp that runs on the JVM, and has a variant that transpiles to JavaScript.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Clojure is not Common Lisp. It's like suggesting perl for someone asking for C.

Comment: @KrishnaSingh Scheme is not Common Lisp.

Comment: Well obviously, and that's a poor comparison. If you know CL and Java, Clojure would be fairly easy to learn. and the Java interop is much nicer than in your example. It depends if you want long term or short term pain. This question is at best a library request, so I was throwing out a suggestion before it gets closed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate If you know Common Lisp and Java you don't need to learn anything new if you use ABCL while Clojure is a new lisp dialect that takes roughly the same amount of time to learn as a new algol dialect. The algol dialects Perl and C are basically as different to each other as the lisp dialects Clojure and Common Lisp.  As lisp dialects I would say clojure and CL are farther apart than other options like Scheme and Elisp.

Comment: Please increase question votes.

Comment: @KrishnaSingh We cannot upvote unless you make the question better. I haven't downvoted since I find the question interesting, but it is truely off topic to ask for resources on SO. If you edit your question with concrete library in Java you would like to be available in CL or vice versa  and loose the last sentence I would upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in Common Lisp there probably are many implementation. One I know of is [Armed Bear Common Lisp](http://abcl.org/) and according to their [user documentation](http://abcl.org/doc/abcl-user.html) you can mix host code (eg. Java libraries and classes) and CL code.

## Running Lisp code from Java:

```java
Interpreter interpreter = Interpreter.createInstance();
interpreter.eval("(load \"my-lisp-code.lisp\")");

Symbol myFunctionSym =
          defaultPackage.findAccessibleSymbol(
               "MY-FUNCTION");
     Function myFunction =
          myFunctionSym.getSymbolFunction();
Cons list = 
          (Cons) myFunction.execute(
                        Fixnum.getInstance(64),
                        Fixnum.getInstance(64));
```

## Calling Java from Common Lisp:

```java
public class Main {
    public int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

```lisp
(defun void-function (param)
  (let* ((class (jclass "Main"))
         (intclass (jclass "int"))
         (method (jmethod class "addTwoNumbers" intclass intclass))
         (result (jcall method param 2 4)))
    (format t "in void-function, result of calling addTwoNumbers(2, 4): ~a~%" result)))
```

The [Lisp Wiki page](http://www.cliki.net/Java) about CL and Java integration has other solutions as well. I especially have hopes for Cloak. As ABCL implements CL running on JVM, Cloak seem to implement JVM under SBCL.

Comment: If you use ABCL, [JSS](https://github.com/slyrus/abcl/tree/master/contrib/jss) is a nice addition to simplify syntax : `(#"addTwoNumbers" "Main" 2 4)` (if I recall correctly)

Comment: I know only lisp

Comment: Not common-lisp

Comment: @KrishnaSingh "lisp" isn't a language. It's a family of languages. From your profile, you appear to know Scheme.

Comment: (defun solve (expression)
  (if (atom expression)
      expression
    (eval (list (second expression)
                (solve (first expression))
                (solve (third expression))))))

Comment: @Carcigenicate i know only above type of lisp.

Comment: @KrishnaSingh I'm not sure there's enough there to say what dialect it is. You should know what dialect of lisp you're writing though, shouldn't you?

Comment: @KrishnaSingh As mentioned LISP isn't really one language, but a group of languages with the same syntax as the 1960s first one named Lisp that does not exist anymore but Common Lisp is a direct decendant of. Programs in lisp need to be very short and simple for them to work under more than one implementation. Perl, C, and PHP are all algol languages I don't say I program algol. `defun` is used by Common Lisp and perhaps Emacs Lisp. Which program do you use today to run your lisp code? (that might implicate which language)

Comment: @Svante So you cannot use streams, but standard 1,4 should work to the same extent it did in 2007. For a conrete file I would just have tried it as it only takes an hour or so to dismiss it from the pool of solutions.